# FancyBox with Slick slider issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, slick.js

I added fancybox and slick slider and its working perfectly but there is 1 problem that i cannot resolve when you slide images inside fancybox lets say you have 2 images in the slider then you clicked on images to view other images in fancybox slide when you scroll over 2 more images and goes to the 3rd images then you close the fancybox slide it reset width and height of slick slider images and it goes half of the image for example image number 1 goes 50% and number 2 images goes full width and height and image number 3 goes 50% width also.

here is my code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide-images">

<div><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="Image/image1.jpg"><img src="Image/image1"></a></div>
<div><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="Image/image2.jpg"><img src="Image/image2"></a></div>
<div><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="Image/image3.jpg"><img src="Image/image3"></a></div>
<div><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="Image/image4.jpg"><img src="Image/image4"></a></div>
<div><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="Image/image5.jpg"><img src="Image/image5"></a></div>
<div><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="Image/image6.jpg"><img src="Image/image6"></a></div>
<div><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="Image/image7.jpg"><img src="Image/image7"></a></div>
<div><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="Image/image8.jpg"><img src="Image/image8"></a></div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.slide-images').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow : 2,
    slidesToScroll:2,
    nextArrow : '<button><i class="fas fa-arrow-square-right"></i></button>',
    prevArrow : '<button><i class="fas fa-arrow-square-left"></i></button>',
  });
```

Images of what i get :

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAFzO.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag7eh.jpg)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8tTF.jpg)

Comment: Are all of your images the same dimensions?

Comment: no they are not the same , but that is not the problem because i tried both same dimensions and sizes but i get the same problem.

Comment: is there something wrong with my code ? :(

Comment: The JS looks fine, but it's hard to troubleshoot the interaction with Fancybox without a working example. Is the behavior any different without the `infinite` option?

Comment: when i disable the infinite from slick slider , it has the same problem , the problem presents when you scroll over fancybox slider then close it like this example : codepen.io/DmiE/pen/rNaOZOL you can set slidesToShow : 2 , you will see the problem , the problem solves when slidesToShow = Odd numbers but it resize slider carousel when you try to put an even number

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue in your CodePen by adding the setting, `variableWidth: true`.

```
$(".main-slider").slick({
  slidesToShow : 2,
  infinite : true,
  dots     : false,
  arrows   : false,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With fancybox 3.5.7 in my case the problem seemed to be `backFocus`

So ended up initializing the instance like this

```
$("[data-fancybox='images']").fancybox({
  backFocus: false,
});
```